# Flow can't see that my array is not empty?

Tags: flowtype

Considering the following code :

```js
const size = 500
const indexes = new Array(size).fill(0).map((_,idx) => idx)
let vals 
if (!vals) {
  vals = new Array(size).fill(0)
}
indexes.forEach(v => vals[v]++)
```

> Note: I understand this code might look strange. forEaching an array (indexes) and use value as index for another one (vals) might not be usual. But it works and I just tried to make a simple case of a real use-case.

Flow returns this error :

```
indexes.forEach(v => vals[v]++)
                    ^ access of computed property/element. Computed property/element cannot be accessed on possibly undefined value
indexes.forEach(v => vals[v]++)
                    ^ uninitialized variable
```

(You can try it on [flow.org/try](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzFwEsAvAUzAF4wBWABntRnMIDcBDGXMVYqMAAoAhJ24BKMAG9UYMGJ41s5JAEEATuo4BPQSQriAdFGIwYg+uNQBfVAsMBbDgAdBbagD55XXAG02ALoA1EFWwMBgCHDqANY8CMT4ABZgAFyo4d7cji5unlk8AGSFBf4BYMWlgSHiQA))

to remove the error, I have to change the last line to verify vals on each iteration :

```js
indexes.forEach(v => vals && vals[v] && vals[v]++)
```

The error vanish also if I replace vals declaration with something initialised immediately

```js
let vals = new Array(size).fill(0)
```

(So using an array values as indexes to another array doesn't seem to be a problem)

Shouldn't flow be able to understand that vals is defined ?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Flow is possibly not able to infer the value to that level so you could do like this

```
const size = 500
let vals 
if (!vals) {
  vals = new Array(size).fill(0)
}
let newVals = vals
vals.map(v => newVals[v]++)
```

Comment: Thanks. But your response make flow look more strange to me :(.
This case seems so dumb. newVals is correct why vals is not ?
Unbelievable.

Comment: The issue is probably due to the fact that you are changing the data type of vals from **undefined** to **array**. Ideally vals should be of type **array** from the point its initialised.

Comment: i agree with @HarshVardhan, that's the only way... Flow is not smart so we need to cover every segment of code in the way he understand :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here isn't because flow thinks the array is empty. It's because flow assumes the conditional initialization is in fact *conditional*, whereas you know that the `if` branch will always be executed.

Flow is looking at the types, not the values. (Even though some of the values can be known at compile time)

As far as Flow is concerned,

```
if (<boolean expression here>) {
  vals = new Array(size).fill(0)
}
```

may or may not initialize `vals`.

The easiest solution is to remove the unnecessary `if` to make it clear that `vals` is always initialized:

```
const size = 500
const indexes = new Array(size).fill(0).map((_,idx) => idx)
let vals 
//if (!vals) {
  vals = new Array(size).fill(0)
//}
indexes.forEach(v => vals[v]++)
```

[Try it here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzFwEsAvAUzAF4wBWABnsxwLGOwBNyAPc3asNnJIAggCcxAQwCeAChIUAlADooxGDFn0VAW0kAHWbID6AGmIdui6gD42lxahjlCAN0kx+qYMGJQwsgCE7p7WAN6oYGAh-DRCohIy8mTkKmoaWo4+AL6o7Fy8uKpwYgCikhgAFrKuttEeuADargC6ANRtikA)

Or even better:

```
const size = 500
const indexes = new Array(size).fill(0).map((_,idx) => idx)
const vals = new Array(size).fill(0)
indexes.forEach(v => vals[v]++)
```

[Try it here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBjOA7AzgFzFwEsAvAUzAF4wBWABnsxwLGOwBNyAPc3asNnJIAggCcxAQwCeAChIUAlADooxGDFn0VAW0kAHWbID6AGmIdui6gD42lxczyEAbpJj8aQ0RJnyy5CpqGlqO7Fy8uKpwYgCikhgAFrIutmBuHgDaLgC6ANR5jkA)